# Oracle MAF : Log file for Android Emulator

Tags: logging, android-emulator, oracle-maf

I'm using Oracle MAF for mobile app development. And I know that, log file will get generate into device file path when we deployed into the Android device. Also I'm getting log in device.

But when we deploy the `Oracle MAF` into `Android emulator` where I could find the application log. I'm having my default logger file (`Dalvik Logger Mechanism`), attached below for you reference.

**logging.properties**

```
# default all loggers to use the ConsoleHandler
.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
# default all loggers to use the SimpleFormatter
.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
# default ConsoleHandler logging level to SEVERE
oracle.adfmf.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=SEVERE

oracle.adfmf.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=oracle.adfmf.util.logging.PatternFormatter
oracle.adfmf.util.logging.PatternFormatter.pattern=[%LEVEL% - %LOGGER% - %CLASS% - %METHOD%] %MESSAGE%

#configure the framework logger to only use the adfmf ConsoleHandler
oracle.adfmf.framework.useParentHandlers=false
oracle.adfmf.framework.handlers=oracle.adfmf.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
oracle.adfmf.framework.level=SEVERE

#configure the application logger to only use the adfmf ConsoleHandler
oracle.adfmf.application.useParentHandlers=false
oracle.adfmf.application.handlers=oracle.adfmf.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
oracle.adfmf.application.level=SEVERE
```

**Emulator Settings:**

[image]

**Android Emulator:**

[image]

Please let me know, if you want any more details regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

**For the Android Emulator:**

The output is forwarded to a text file with the same name as the application. The output file location is /sdcard. If this location is not present or is configured as read-only, the log output is rerouted to the application's writable data directory.
Source: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/mobile200/mobile/develop-oepe/oepe-maf-debug-test.htm#BABCBIHI (22.4 Using and Configuring Logging)

**For the iOS Simulator:**

Depending on the Oracle MAF version you are using, you should be able to redirect the log file to a location of choice (from 2.1).

This can be archieved by adding some Application Arguments: On your application, select Run >>> Choose Active Run Configuration >>> Manage Run Configurations where you should add following argument `-consoleRedirect=<your location/logFile.txt>`

Comment: yeah., I got the log under /sdcard ("My Files" folder) in android device. But in case of emulator i did't see such folder, I updated question with emulator screen shot please check it once.

Comment: I could able to get log file in simulator as well. Is there any way to get log file in iOS physical device?